# How to capture error message returned from linked server?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, linked-server

How can I capture an error message returned from a linked server?

As an example, if I run the following command in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
BEGIN TRY
 exec ('select * from xxx') at my_linked_server
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  print  'ErrorNumber...'+  CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar)
  print  'ErrorSeverity...'+  CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() as varchar)
  print  'ErrorState...'+  CAST(ERROR_STATE() as varchar)
  print  'ErrorProcedure...'+ IsNull(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'')
  print  'ErrorLine...'+  CAST(ERROR_LINE() as varchar)
  print  'ErrorMessage...'+  IsNull(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')
END CATCH
```

I get the following results:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "my_linked_server" returned message "[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]The specified table (xxx) is not in the database.".
>   ErrorNumber...7215
>   ErrorSeverity...17
>   ErrorState...1
>   ErrorProcedure...
>   ErrorLine...3
>   ErrorMessage...Could not execute statement on remote server 'my_linked_server'.

Does SQL Server store the OLE DB provider error?  (It would be useful to capture this info for debugging.)

Comment: @jjj - this could fall equally into a dev arena.

Comment: this question from yesterday and no answers....!!

..OoO..i would if i could give some thing usefull

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I found out how to get around it by passing the try catch to the linked server and getting the error back using the `OUTPUT` parameter. For example:

```
    SET @command = '
    BEGIN TRY
        exec (''select * from xxx'') 
        SELECT @resultOUT = @@ERROR
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @resultOUT = @@ERROR
    END CATCH'
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@resultOUT nvarchar(5) OUTPUT'
    exec my_linked_server.sp_executesql 
        @command, 
        @ParmDefinition, 
        @resultOUT=@result OUTPUT
```