# Catching Errors through a linked server with severity < 20

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, try-catch, linked-server

I've got a similar problem to this question: [TRY CATCH with Linked Server in SQL Server 2005 Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503607/try-catch-with-linked-server-in-sql-server-2005-not-working)

I'm running this try catch:

```
    Declare @command nvarchar(100)
    SET @command = 'SELECT column FROM table'
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRY
            exec ' + @Server_Name + @DB_name + '.dbo.sp_executesql @command
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT EXCEPTION
    END CATCH
```

I don't think I can use `RAISEERROR` because I'm not running my own stored procedure, I'm only running a simple select statement. I've tried using `@@ERROR` but that doesn't work across a linked server either. Because the error I get is less than 20, I run into this problem:

> If a remote stored procedure calls RAISERROR with severity less than
>   20 and the remote stored procedure is scoped within a TRY block on the
>   local server, RAISERROR does not cause control to pass to the CATCH
>   block of the TRY…CATCH construct

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191515.aspx

I found this question: [How to capture error message returned from linked server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168207/how-to-capture-error-message-returned-from-linked-server?rq=1) which has not been answered either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to get around this by passing the try catch to the linked server and getting the error back using the OUTPUT parameter. For example:

```
SET @command = '
BEGIN TRY
    exec (''select * from xxx'') 
    SELECT @resultOUT = @@ERROR
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @resultOUT = @@ERROR
END CATCH'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@resultOUT nvarchar(5) OUTPUT'
exec my_linked_server.sp_executesql 
    @command, 
    @ParmDefinition, 
    @resultOUT=@result OUTPUT
```