# Catch does not pass error_message() to remote stored procedure called inside catch

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, try-catch

I created a small logging framework so I can easily call a stored procedure like spLog or spLogError.

The stored procedures and tables all reside in a separate database called Logging.

Now the code that I use looks as follows:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.testLogProcLinkedServer') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.testLogProcLinkedServer;
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testLogProcLinkedServer]
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;

    declare @msg nvarchar(max),
            @dbId int = db_id();

    begin try
        declare @i int;

        set @i = 1 / 0;
    end try
    begin catch
        exec [MyLinkedServer].[Logging].dbo.spLogError  @objectId = @@PROCID, 
                                                        @databaseId = @dbId, 
                                                        @message = N'Testing catch errors, check field ErrorMessage for more information.';
    end catch
end
go

exec dbo.testLogProcLinkedServer;
```

Now the thing is that ERROR_MESSAGE() does not get into the spLogError, it is NULL. But when I remove MyLinkedServer (on my development environment, the databases are on the same server so there I am able to do this), the ERROR_MESSAGE() is available and all is working as intended.

When looking up "tsql catch linked server" on Google. 
I find this SO question:
[Catching Errors through a linked server with severity < 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315128/catching-errors-through-a-linked-server-with-severity-20)

But the main difference with this question and mine, is that the most topics are refering to catching an error from a remote procedure call, but I don't want to catch something from a remote procedure call.
I would like to send it my error data and write the corresponding table.

Can anyone point me to what is causing this?

Comment: I don't see `ERROR_MESSAGE()` in your code. Is that it in the remote `spLogError` proc? If so, you need to instead get the value in the code before calling the remote proc and pass the value to the remote proc (e.g. as part of the `@message` parameter).

Comment: Hi Dan, yes it is part of the stored proc spLogError. You are right in that I should pass it with the @message parameter. But why is my question. The procedure is inside the catch scope, so shouldn't that procedure be aware of what Error_message() is?

Comment: The error context is out of scope in the remote proc. Error context is only available on the local server and not serialized for access in remote calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ERROR_MESSAGE()` and other error context functions are only available in the local `CATCH` block. The remote procedure is oblivious to the fact it's called from a `CATCH` block and doesn't have access to the error context.

You'll need to pass the value to the remote `spLogError` as a parameter value for logging purposes.

```
BEGIN CATCH
    @msg = N'Testing catch errors, ErrorMessage value is: '
        + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    EXEC [MyLinkedServer].[Logging].dbo.spLogError  @objectId = @@PROCID, 
                                                    @databaseId = @dbId, 
                                                    @message = @msg;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is it stated anywhere in the docs? As I was not able to find it on Google. Normally such things pop up immediately.

Comment: I'm not aware of this being called out in the docs but it makes sense when you think about it. There's nothing special about `ERROR_MESSAGE()`. It's that the remote server has no knowledge of the calling session context (sans maybe distributed transaction info) and all system functions that return session context information (e.g. `@@SPID`, `HOST_NAME()`, et.al.) return information about the session of the instance running the code. The calling server would need to pass all that information in order for it to be available remotely.